# What coding system should I use for one Emacs configurations for both unix and Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, character-encoding

I set the coding as `utf-8`, and I got many `^M` from `eshell` on Windows. There's `utf-8-dos` and `utf-8-unix`. I would like to use the same configuration file on both unix and Windows. I guess there are many people work on the two system from time to time. How do you handle this?

Comment: I see you've been asking a few Windows related questions. I too work on Windows a lot. My solution is close to being a non-answer, so I'll post it as a comment: I use Cygwin. It's just so much better there's really no comparison. It eliminates many coding issues (I keep all the Emacs defaults). I use 32-bit because it's compatible with more software. I also use the Emacs package with native Windows GUI (called "emacs-w32"). It makes TRAMP usable with no configuration besides installing Cygwin ssh/gnutls/inetutils packages. And of course you get all the great *nix and GNU software.

Comment: Hmm. I don't use emacs on windows, but in my experience, emacs auto-detects the line ending conventions with a near 100% success rate. So I am afraid I don't quite understand your problem … oh wait, I just noticed the reference to `eshell`. That changes things a bit. Hang on, I'll have more to say in a moment …

Comment: So, you want just one configuration file, which is fine, but then some things need to be different depending on the OS. Two useful variables to use are `system-type` and `window-system` (the latter is non-nil only in GUI emacs). Check out their values on the systems you usually run on, then conditionalize your configuration as needed using these variables.

Comment: For the last month or so I've been "returning to Windows" that that includes Emacs. Like nanny, I'm going the W32 route but with http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/ instead of cygwin. That is the GNU Emacs endorsed approach and I like it because it is 'just a download' instead of asking someone to use cygwin. I will post my updated config within a month because thus far it has worked fine. All of the "on-windows" macro calls make it work right, at least for me.